# Add hidden class to items except active

Tags: javascript, css

I would like to be able to click on a div, and have the clicked div expand, while all of the other divs disappear by having a "hidden" class added to them (I've created a "hidden" class for this). I have an "active" class, which when added to a div, does the job of expanding out the div as desired. So far, I'm able to add the "active" class to the div on click.

The problem I'm having, is I don't know how to remove the other divs by adding the "hidden" class to them. I assume I need to check to see if they have the active class after the initial click, and if they don't, then hide them, but i'm not certain.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```

Javascript:

```
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

const toggleOpen = (p, e) => {
    p.classList.toggle('active');
}

items.forEach(
item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', toggleOpen.bind(null, item))
})
```

CSS:
Here's my sample code, which allows you to add an active class when clicked.
https://jsfiddle.net/a60bur1j/8/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would just do it with CSS with a class on the parent container.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('.item');

const toggleOpen = (p, e) => {
    p.classList.toggle('active');
    p.parentNode.classList.toggle('active');
}

items.forEach(
item => {
    item.addEventListener('click', toggleOpen.bind(null, item))
})
```

```css
.container.active div.active {
   display: block;
}

.container.active div {
   display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
</div>
```